# Print query with loops in it and condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a foreach function which permits me to print fields in a database,

I want to do possible that if `$row[value]="photo"` don't just print the `$row[value]` but another thing.

Can I do it?

The code is this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
        echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>"; 
    }
```

I need to have a condition that `if $row[value]=photo` to echo another thing not: `echo "<td>" . $row[$photo] . "</td>"`;

Any example?

Comment: Yep, that's entirely possible. Show us the code you've written that isn't working, and we'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i could not get what to print for `if($row['value'] == photo)` check, so add that code yourself in the code written below.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
        if($value == 'photo'){
            echo "<td><img src = '".$row[$value]."'></td>"; 
        }else{
        echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>"; 
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need to be complex.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    if ($row['value'] === 'photo') {
        // print "another thing"
    } else {
        // print "something"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just include an if statement with that. Your code will be similar to the code below:

```
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if($value == "one")
       echo "Not gonna print one.";
    else
       echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Using your code, you can see if the value is *not* `photo`, echo it.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
        if($row[value] == "photo") {
            echo "some other thing";
        } else {
            echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What i need to do is to check if the photo value is there, if it is it should be printed otherwise.. i need to put a "img src" that's why...

Comment: You can do all that with an if statement. Try writing out the psuedo code "if this then this, otherwise this" and then just convert it into PHP syntax.

Comment: Ok so the pseudocode would be this:
foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
check if there is a row[value]=photo, if there is print all row[value] but the one of the row[photo] you should print it with a img src before the code]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print img src if the field is "photo" field (key) then
Try this :

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
            if($key == 'photo'){
                echo "<td><img src = '".$row[$value]."'></td>"; 
            }else{
            echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>"; 
            }
       }
    }
```